# DataGridView TextBox column with Autocomplete that populates other cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, autocomplete, .net-4.0

I have a simple DataGridView:

[image: DataGridView]

I have a class:

```
public class TemplateItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And a list to store templates:

```
List<TemplateItem> templates = new List<TemplateItem>();
// Some code to populate the list
```

For the "Name" cell in the grid, I want to:

- display autocomplete options from the `templates` list when the user types in the cell
- automatically set the "Price" cell to the price of the autocomplete option that the user has selected (the user can change the price afterwards)
- allow the user to type in something not available in the `templates` list

I know how to enable autocomplete by using EditingControlShowing event, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225290/textbox-autocomplete-in-a-datagridview-winform).

I don't know how to detect the selection of an autocomplete option. [Using KeyDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642981/how-get-event-item-selected-with-autocomplete-in-c) doesn't work for me - it never fires.

And I don't know how to get the price of the selected option. Supposing I was able to catch the "option selected" event, I could go through the templates and find the one with the same name... but that seems ugly code to me. I should be able to pass the information about the price for each option somehow, right?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-modifying my user interface, so that the grid no longer allows the user to enter new rows. Instead, I have a separate `ComboBox` (`DropDownStyle` set to `DropDown`) with autosuggest turned on and an "add" button to insert new rows based on the value from the combobox. If an existing template is selected, its price is inserted as well; otherwise, just the entered text is inserted.

If anyone knows of how to achieve the same functionality within the datagridview, please let me know.